# ArcObjects: identifier for ICommandBars.Find

Tags: arcobjects

I am looking for the identifiers for the method `ICommandBars.Find(object identifier)` method in the ArcObjects. During web search I found the following [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00230000006v000000), that used the class `ArcID`, but I cannot find it anywhere.

I need to get the `CommandItem`for the `Start Editing` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this [page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000029s000000). You can use or execute it as follows:

```
        object helpme = "{59D2AFD0-9EA2-11D1-9165-0080C718DF97}";
        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
        uid.Value = helpme;
        //For accessing some sub menues you can use the SubType attribute
        //uid.SubType = 9;

        //Search the commandbars
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars;

        //Find the command
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid, false, false);

        //Execute the command
        if (commandItem != null)
        {
            commandItem.Execute();
        }
```